# How to find ARM processor version on android device?

Tags: android, adb

I tried the following command and it worked fine on a couple of devices.

```
adb shell getprop | grep abi
```

This command fails to get the ARM processor version for some devices. Is there any other way to find out what version of ARM processor is my device running on?

Thanks

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Try

```
adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Comment: It also works to enter `cat /proc/cpuinfo` into a console on the phone if that works (root need, terminal emulator, possibly even GravityBox, …)

Answer (score 157):

Execute the following command:

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi
```

Comment: Tried 'sudo waydroid shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi' on Waydroid 1.4.2, it also works, incredible!

Answer (score 64):

There is also:

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abilist
```

Comment: It prints like `x86,armeabi-v7a,armeabi`. What is my device's arhictecture?

Comment: @jinbeomhong take a look at https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis . It explains the architecture of each abi.

Answer (score 15):

Try,

```
adb shell getprop | grep ro.product.cpu.abi
```

It would give you the abi type based on which you can find which arch the device belongs to.

Reference : https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis

Eg;

```
x86         - 32 bit x86 architecture
x86_64      - 64 bit x86 architecture
armeabi-v7a - 32 bit arm architecture
arm64-v8a   - 64 bit arm architecuture
```

Comment: The command may need to be quoted: `adb shell "getprop | grep ro.product.cpu.abi"`

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me is a mix of two methods. Firs I try

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abilist
```

And if it is not clear (in case of Huawei Octacores) you can use

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi
```