# Is it possible to turn on developer options for the emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

The Developer Options for Android are really useful.  But I can't seem to enable them on an Android emulator (Nexus 5 running API 25).  I tried clicking with my mouse 7 times on the build number to simulate the 7 taps on a phone.  But the Developer Options don't appear.

Comment: It works with API 28.

Answer (score 35):

I have found a video on YouTube and worked for me.
The way you enable it is the same as you'd do in a real device. 
Go to: Settings -> System -> About emulated device -> Build number click that as many times as it takes to turn on developer mode, and that's it!

Here is the video:

https://youtu.be/Yxqq7bT1K2A

Comment: It worked fine for me. I think it would not work in hardware that you'd have to press some sort of combination of keys or something. Since I have not seen such hardware it may work for all.

Comment: This video is out of date and no longer works with the latest Android Studio.

Comment: worked for me as well. thanks,

didn't go for video, just  `Go to: Settings -> System -> About emulated device -> Build number click that as many times` worked

Answer (score 17):

`Developer options` is not enabled by default. Below are the steps to enable it in your emulator

1. Go to `Settings` -> `About emulated device`
2. Click `Build number` 7 times (or till it says that you're a developer now).
3. Go back and go to `System` -> `Advanced` -> `Developer options`

Answer (score 6):

`adb shell input keyevent 82` is the command

Answer (score 3):

For me the tapping on the build number didn't work on my Emulator.

I used this command instead and it worked:

`adb shell settings put global development_settings_enabled 1`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not possible to turn on the Developer Options in the Android emulator because the documentation calls them *On-Device* Developer Options: [Configure On-Device Developer Options](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options).  That said, I don't see an explicit mention that it can't be used on the emulator.  I looked in the [Configure On-Device Developer Options](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options) and the [Run Apps on the Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator?utm_source=android-studio) documentation.

Perhaps the On-Device Developer Options are handled in other ways by the Android emulator.  For example, there are the [Extended controls, settings, and help](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#extended).  There are also the command-line options you can pass to the Android emulator.

Some options may simply be unavailable on an Android Emulator, such as [Try out WebView Beta](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/androidwebview/android-webview-beta).  Each limitation such as this one may or may not workaround.  A possible workaround for updating the WebView on the Android Emulator is [Update Android System WebView on SDK Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785197/update-android-system-webview-on-sdk-emulator).

Answer (score -1):

To enable 'develper options' in real phone or emulator, we may refer to the official document.
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options.
I did it on Pixel 2 API28 emulator following instrucions explained in the link and it worked.
Have a good one!