# Unknown AVD name, use -list-avds to see valid list

Tags: android, sdk

I'm trying to setup an Android Emulator in order to use Cordova. I installed everything I need, the Android SDK Tools (25.2.5), Android SDK Build-tools (25.*) and Android SDK Platform-tools, along with every packet under Android 7.1.1 (API 25). I then go to andoird avd and choose to create an AVD based on one of the templates (google nexus 5) with the default name (AVD_for_Nexus_5_by_Google). However, when i go run it on "Android Virtual Devices", i get the error message:

> "Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_5_by_Google' PANIC: Unknown
>   AVD name [AVD_for_Nexus_5_by_Google], use -list-avds to see valid
>   list. HOME is defined but could not find AVD_for_Nexus_5_by_Google.ini
>   file in $HOME/.android/avd (Note: avd is searched in the order of
>   $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd and
>   $HOME/.android/avd)"

If i just have created it, why doesn't it show up? 
When i do "*emulator -list-avds*", nothing shows up. And when i do an "**ls /root/.android/avd**" on , i can see both files: "**AVD_for_Nexus_5_by_Google.avd  AVD_for_Nexus_5_by_Google.ini**"

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

The problem was that i hadn't defined the env variables. To fix this put this lines in a text file (modify the directories accordingly):

> export ANDROID_HOME=/root/Android/Sdk/ export
>   PATH=${PATH}:/root/Android/Sdk/tools/ export
>   ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/root/.android/avd/

And then do a "source /textfile" in the terminal you're using. If you're not sure which directory's storing your avd, do a "updatedb && locate *.avd"

Comment: after adding it fixed the original error but I got emulator Missing initial data partition file

Comment: Obviously, you are not on windows. 
What is `updatedb`?  I presume the `locate` command is in my source code directory and should actually be `dir /s/b *.avd`  right?

Comment: Path on Windows: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools` , this is notably where the `emulator` binary is located in.