Why is my Ionic app not working on Android 7 with Vue?
I created a new ionic project and selected vuejs, I didn't do anything except:
ionic build
ionic cap add android
ionic cap copy
ionic cap sync
ionic cap open android

I have an Android 7 virtual device. I ran the program on it using the run button at the top in the Android-Studio program. The program opens and nothing appears, while for example in Android 11 it works normally:
Android 7 :

Android 7 logcat :
2024-11-14 14:28:37.843  3348-3348  System                  io.ionic.starter                     W  ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/io.ionic.starter-1/lib/x86
2024-11-14 14:28:37.911  3348-3348  AppCompatDelegate       io.ionic.starter                     D  Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
2024-11-14 14:28:37.922  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
2024-11-14 14:28:37.964  3348-3348  System                  io.ionic.starter                     W  ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/Chrome/lib/x86
2024-11-14 14:28:37.965  3348-3348  WebViewFactory          io.ionic.starter                     I  Loading com.android.chrome version 51.0.2704.90 (code 275509012)
2024-11-14 14:28:38.031  3348-3348  cr_LibraryLoader        io.ionic.starter                     I  Time to load native libraries: 12 ms (timestamps 3127-3139)
2024-11-14 14:28:38.031  3348-3348  cr_LibraryLoader        io.ionic.starter                     I  Expected native library version number "51.0.2704.90", actual native library version number "51.0.2704.90"
2024-11-14 14:28:38.266  3348-3348  WebViewChr...ryProvider io.ionic.starter                     V  Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {61384fc}
2024-11-14 14:28:38.266  3348-3348  cr_LibraryLoader        io.ionic.starter                     I  Expected native library version number "51.0.2704.90", actual native library version number "51.0.2704.90"
2024-11-14 14:28:38.278  3348-3348  chromium                io.ionic.starter                     I  [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(143)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
2024-11-14 14:28:38.396  3348-3348  cr_BrowserStartup       io.ionic.starter                     I  Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
2024-11-14 14:28:38.425  3348-3348  ApkAssets               io.ionic.starter                     E  Error while loading asset assets/natives_blob_64.bin: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/natives_blob_64.bin
2024-11-14 14:28:38.425  3348-3348  ApkAssets               io.ionic.starter                     E  Error while loading asset assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin
2024-11-14 14:28:38.459  3348-3348  <no-tag>                io.ionic.starter                     D  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x97fe4040, tid 3348
2024-11-14 14:28:38.489  3348-3348  EGL_emulation           io.ionic.starter                     D  eglCreateContext: 0xa55ac100: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2024-11-14 14:28:38.508  3348-3348  EGL_emulation           io.ionic.starter                     D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xa55ac100: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb05d15a0)
2024-11-14 14:28:38.713  3348-3412  cr_media                io.ionic.starter                     W  Requires BLUETOOTH permission
2024-11-14 14:28:38.755  3348-3348  cr_Ime                  io.ionic.starter                     D  [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:30] Constructor
2024-11-14 14:28:38.769  3348-3348  cr_AwContents           io.ionic.starter                     W  onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
2024-11-14 14:28:38.770  3348-3348  cr_Ime                  io.ionic.starter                     D  [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: false
2024-11-14 14:28:38.772  3348-3348  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Starting BridgeActivity
2024-11-14 14:28:38.790  3348-3348  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Registering plugin instance: CapacitorCookies
2024-11-14 14:28:38.795  3348-3348  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Registering plugin instance: WebView
2024-11-14 14:28:38.796  3348-3348  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Registering plugin instance: CapacitorHttp
2024-11-14 14:28:38.797  3348-3348  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Registering plugin instance: App
2024-11-14 14:28:38.798  3348-3348  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Registering plugin instance: Haptics
2024-11-14 14:28:38.802  3348-3348  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Registering plugin instance: Keyboard
2024-11-14 14:28:38.802  3348-3348  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Registering plugin instance: StatusBar
2024-11-14 14:28:38.849  3348-3348  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     W  Unable to read file at path public/plugins
2024-11-14 14:28:38.850  3348-3348  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Loading app at https://localhost
2024-11-14 14:28:38.856  3348-3348  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     E  System WebView is not supported
2024-11-14 14:28:38.878  3348-3348  cr_Ime                  io.ionic.starter                     I  ImeThread is not enabled.
2024-11-14 14:28:38.903  3348-3348  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  App started
2024-11-14 14:28:38.997  3348-3348  Capacitor/AppPlugin     io.ionic.starter                     D  Firing change: true
2024-11-14 14:28:38.997  3348-3348  Capacitor/AppPlugin     io.ionic.starter                     V  Notifying listeners for event appStateChange
2024-11-14 14:28:38.997  3348-3348  Capacitor/AppPlugin     io.ionic.starter                     D  No listeners found for event appStateChange
2024-11-14 14:28:38.998  3348-3348  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  App resumed
2024-11-14 14:28:39.122  3348-3348  Choreographer           io.ionic.starter                     I  Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2024-11-14 14:28:39.226  3348-3454  OpenGLRenderer          io.ionic.starter                     I  Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2024-11-14 14:28:39.292  3348-3454  OpenGLRenderer          io.ionic.starter                     D  Swap behavior 1
2024-11-14 14:28:39.292  3348-3454  <no-tag>                io.ionic.starter                     D  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x95fbfa80, tid 3454
2024-11-14 14:28:39.292  3348-3454  OpenGLRenderer          io.ionic.starter                     W  Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2024-11-14 14:28:39.292  3348-3454  OpenGLRenderer          io.ionic.starter                     D  Swap behavior 0
2024-11-14 14:28:39.299  3348-3454  EGL_emulation           io.ionic.starter                     D  eglCreateContext: 0xb4205a20: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2024-11-14 14:28:39.316  3348-3454  EGL_emulation           io.ionic.starter                     D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xb4205a20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb4203a70)
2024-11-14 14:28:39.473  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:39.475  3348-3454  EGL_emulation           io.ionic.starter                     D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xb4205a20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb4203a70)
2024-11-14 14:28:39.523  3348-3463  libEGL                  io.ionic.starter                     E  validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
2024-11-14 14:28:39.568  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:39.634  3348-3406  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Handling local request: https://localhost/
2024-11-14 14:28:39.693  3348-3359  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Suspending all threads took: 19.172ms
2024-11-14 14:28:39.701  3348-3359  art                     io.ionic.starter                     I  Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 716(85KB) AllocSpace objects, 12(4MB) LOS objects, 36% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 20.400ms total 134.843ms
2024-11-14 14:28:39.776  3348-3463  VideoCapabilities       io.ionic.starter                     I  Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
2024-11-14 14:28:39.784  3348-3463  <no-tag>                io.ionic.starter                     D  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x940b56c0, tid 3463
2024-11-14 14:28:39.816  3348-3463  EGL_emulation           io.ionic.starter                     D  eglCreateContext: 0xb4206140: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2024-11-14 14:28:39.818  3348-3463  EGL_emulation           io.ionic.starter                     D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xb4206140: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x952d4460)
2024-11-14 14:28:39.882  3348-3348  cr_BindingManager       io.ionic.starter                     W  Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 3348
2024-11-14 14:28:39.884  3348-3348  cr_Ime                  io.ionic.starter                     D  [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
2024-11-14 14:28:39.884  3348-3348  cr_Ime                  io.ionic.starter                     D  [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
2024-11-14 14:28:39.967  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:39.983  3348-3406  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Handling local request: https://localhost/assets/index-pvFfJh0g.js
2024-11-14 14:28:39.985  3348-3406  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Handling local request: https://localhost/assets/index-7CQuqmcz.css
2024-11-14 14:28:39.986  3348-3406  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Handling local request: https://localhost/assets/polyfills-legacy-Crc_c0-N.js
2024-11-14 14:28:40.002  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.005  3348-3348  Capacitor/Console       io.ionic.starter                     E  File: https://localhost/ - Line 54 - Msg: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
2024-11-14 14:28:40.046  3348-3348  Capacitor/Console       io.ionic.starter                     W  File: https://localhost/ - Line 1296 - Msg: The key "viewport-fit" is not recognized and ignored.
2024-11-14 14:28:40.079  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.083  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.097  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.110  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.130  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.145  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.163  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.179  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.213  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.228  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.245  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.269  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.272  3348-3348  Capacitor/Console       io.ionic.starter                     E  File: https://localhost/assets/polyfills-legacy-Crc_c0-N.js - Line 4 - Msg: Uncaught (in promise) Error: assets/index-legacy-DhofhxmR.js, https://localhost/ (SystemJS https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/main/docs/errors.md#8)
2024-11-14 14:28:40.278  3348-3406  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Handling local request: https://localhost/favicon.png
2024-11-14 14:28:40.827  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.850  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.864  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.880  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.908  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.931  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.945  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.963  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:40.981  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:41.001  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:41.014  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:41.035  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:41.046  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:41.063  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:41.079  3348-3348  art                     io.ionic.starter                     W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2024-11-14 14:28:45.154  3348-3886  ProfileInstaller        io.ionic.starter                     D  Installing profile for io.ionic.starter
2024-11-14 14:28:52.834  3348-3355  art                     io.ionic.starter                     I  Debugger is no longer active
2024-11-14 14:28:52.834  3348-3355  art                     io.ionic.starter                     I  Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation

Note that the program is new!
Android 11 :

Android 11 logcat :
2024-11-14 14:35:04.648  2653-2653  o.ionic.starte          io.ionic.starter                     I  Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2024-11-14 14:35:04.655  2653-2653  o.ionic.starte          io.ionic.starter                     I  Unquickening 12 vdex files!
2024-11-14 14:35:04.670  2653-2653  o.ionic.starte          io.ionic.starter                     W  Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2024-11-14 14:35:05.048  2653-2653  NetworkSecurityConfig   io.ionic.starter                     D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2024-11-14 14:35:05.049  2653-2653  NetworkSecurityConfig   io.ionic.starter                     D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2024-11-14 14:35:05.243  2653-2700  libEGL                  io.ionic.starter                     D  loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2024-11-14 14:35:05.248  2653-2700  libEGL                  io.ionic.starter                     D  loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2024-11-14 14:35:05.252  2653-2700  libEGL                  io.ionic.starter                     D  loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2024-11-14 14:35:05.277  2653-2653  AppCompatDelegate       io.ionic.starter                     D  Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
2024-11-14 14:35:05.390  2653-2653  o.ionic.starte          io.ionic.starter                     W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2024-11-14 14:35:05.390  2653-2653  o.ionic.starte          io.ionic.starter                     W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2024-11-14 14:35:05.415  2653-2653  WebViewFactory          io.ionic.starter                     I  Loading com.google.android.webview version 83.0.4103.106 (code 410410681)
2024-11-14 14:35:05.418  2653-2653  o.ionic.starte          io.ionic.starter                     I  The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2024-11-14 14:35:05.419  2653-2653  nativeloader            io.ionic.starter                     D  classloader namespace configured for unbundled product apk. library_path=/product/app/WebViewGoogle/lib/x86:/product/app/WebViewGoogle/WebViewGoogle.apk!/lib/x86:/product/app/TrichromeLibrary/TrichromeLibrary.apk!/lib/x86:/product/lib:/system/product/lib
2024-11-14 14:35:05.452  2653-2653  o.ionic.starte          io.ionic.starter                     I  The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2024-11-14 14:35:05.452  2653-2653  nativeloader            io.ionic.starter                     D  classloader namespace configured for unbundled product apk. library_path=/product/app/WebViewGoogle/lib/x86:/product/app/WebViewGoogle/WebViewGoogle.apk!/lib/x86:/product/app/TrichromeLibrary/TrichromeLibrary.apk!/lib/x86:/product/lib:/system/product/lib
2024-11-14 14:35:05.707  2653-2653  cr_LibraryLoader        io.ionic.starter                     I  Loaded native library version number "83.0.4103.106"
2024-11-14 14:35:05.714  2653-2653  cr_CachingUmaRecorder   io.ionic.starter                     I  Flushed 3 samples from 3 histograms.
2024-11-14 14:35:05.844  2653-2653  chromium                io.ionic.starter                     E  [ERROR:filesystem_posix.cc(62)] mkdir /data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/cache/WebView/Crashpad: No such file or directory (2)
2024-11-14 14:35:05.930  2653-2653  TetheringManager        io.ionic.starter                     I  registerTetheringEventCallback:io.ionic.starter
2024-11-14 14:35:05.999  2653-2773  chromium                io.ionic.starter                     W  [WARNING:dns_config_service_posix.cc(341)] Failed to read DnsConfig.
2024-11-14 14:35:06.166  2653-2653  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Starting BridgeActivity
2024-11-14 14:35:06.215  2653-2653  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Registering plugin instance: CapacitorCookies
2024-11-14 14:35:06.223  2653-2653  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Registering plugin instance: WebView
2024-11-14 14:35:06.226  2653-2653  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Registering plugin instance: CapacitorHttp
2024-11-14 14:35:06.228  2653-2653  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Registering plugin instance: App
2024-11-14 14:35:06.229  2653-2653  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Registering plugin instance: Haptics
2024-11-14 14:35:06.231  2653-2653  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Registering plugin instance: Keyboard
2024-11-14 14:35:06.233  2653-2653  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Registering plugin instance: StatusBar
2024-11-14 14:35:06.262  2653-2653  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     W  Unable to read file at path public/plugins
2024-11-14 14:35:06.266  2653-2653  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Loading app at https://localhost
2024-11-14 14:35:06.288  2653-2774  o.ionic.starte          io.ionic.starter                     W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioManager;->getOutputLatency(I)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2024-11-14 14:35:06.296  2653-2796  HostConnection          io.ionic.starter                     D  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xeef9c7f0, tid 2796
2024-11-14 14:35:06.298  2653-2796  HostConnection          io.ionic.starter                     D  HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_qsri ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2024-11-14 14:35:06.324  2653-2796  chromium                io.ionic.starter                     E  [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(549)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
2024-11-14 14:35:06.331  2653-2774  cr_media                io.ionic.starter                     W  Requires BLUETOOTH permission
2024-11-14 14:35:06.345  2653-2796  EGL_emulation           io.ionic.starter                     D  eglCreateContext: 0xeefa5a80: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2024-11-14 14:35:06.346  2653-2796  EGL_emulation           io.ionic.starter                     D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xeefa5a80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xbff69ad0) (first time)
2024-11-14 14:35:06.406  2653-2653  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  App started
2024-11-14 14:35:06.407  2653-2653  Capacitor/AppPlugin     io.ionic.starter                     D  Firing change: true
2024-11-14 14:35:06.408  2653-2653  Capacitor/AppPlugin     io.ionic.starter                     V  Notifying listeners for event appStateChange
2024-11-14 14:35:06.408  2653-2653  Capacitor/AppPlugin     io.ionic.starter                     D  No listeners found for event appStateChange
2024-11-14 14:35:06.409  2653-2653  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  App resumed
2024-11-14 14:35:06.430  2653-2772  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Handling local request: https://localhost/
2024-11-14 14:35:06.453  2653-2796  chromium                io.ionic.starter                     E  [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(549)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
2024-11-14 14:35:06.474  2653-2653  Choreographer           io.ionic.starter                     I  Skipped 82 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2024-11-14 14:35:06.521  2653-2696  HostConnection          io.ionic.starter                     D  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xeefa4c80, tid 2696
2024-11-14 14:35:06.544  2653-2696  HostConnection          io.ionic.starter                     D  HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_qsri ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2024-11-14 14:35:06.544  2653-2696  OpenGLRenderer          io.ionic.starter                     W  Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2024-11-14 14:35:06.551  2653-2696  EGL_emulation           io.ionic.starter                     D  eglCreateContext: 0xeefa5700: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2024-11-14 14:35:06.608  2653-2696  EGL_emulation           io.ionic.starter                     D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xeefa5700: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xbff4d3b0) (first time)
2024-11-14 14:35:06.636  2653-2696  Gralloc4                io.ionic.starter                     I  mapper 4.x is not supported
2024-11-14 14:35:06.636  2653-2696  HostConnection          io.ionic.starter                     D  createUnique: call
2024-11-14 14:35:06.637  2653-2696  HostConnection          io.ionic.starter                     D  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xeefa5e00, tid 2696
2024-11-14 14:35:06.637  2653-2696  goldfish-address-space  io.ionic.starter                     D  allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
2024-11-14 14:35:06.637  2653-2696  goldfish-address-space  io.ionic.starter                     D  allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fbffe000 size 0x2000
2024-11-14 14:35:06.644  2653-2696  HostConnection          io.ionic.starter                     D  HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_qsri ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2024-11-14 14:35:06.695  2653-2796  VideoCapabilities       io.ionic.starter                     I  Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
2024-11-14 14:35:06.696  2653-2796  cr_MediaCodecUtil       io.ionic.starter                     W  HW encoder for video/avc is not available on this device.
2024-11-14 14:35:06.727  2653-2796  EGL_emulation           io.ionic.starter                     D  eglCreateContext: 0xeefa6e30: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2024-11-14 14:35:06.750  2653-2696  OpenGLRenderer          io.ionic.starter                     I  Davey! duration=1648ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=38656899249, Vsync=40023565861, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=40030744800, AnimationStart=40030767700, PerformTraversalsStart=40031282100, DrawStart=40204287600, SyncQueued=40207387000, SyncStart=40208729300, IssueDrawCommandsStart=40208761700, SwapBuffers=40303013500, FrameCompleted=40306619200, DequeueBufferDuration=192900, QueueBufferDuration=203200, GpuCompleted=72904454231491230, 
2024-11-14 14:35:06.906  2653-2676  o.ionic.starte          io.ionic.starter                     I  Background young concurrent copying GC freed 29128(2380KB) AllocSpace objects, 31(2180KB) LOS objects, 89% free, 2793KB/26MB, paused 12.818ms total 233.591ms
2024-11-14 14:35:07.100  2653-2773  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Handling local request: https://localhost/assets/index-pvFfJh0g.js
2024-11-14 14:35:07.110  2653-2772  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Handling local request: https://localhost/assets/index-7CQuqmcz.css
2024-11-14 14:35:07.814  2653-2770  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Handling local request: https://localhost/assets/Tab1Page-CSdA8T5W.js
2024-11-14 14:35:07.822  2653-2770  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     D  Handling local request: https://localhost/assets/ExploreContainer-rA69k34D.js
...

I cant put more logcat

Android version may not be relevant. It's shown that Chrome 51 webview is used in 7, which is really old and totally expected to not work with modern web app. Webview can be updated apart from os

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019960/how-to-upgrade-androids-webview-in-emulator-android-5

Ionic and Capacitor generally aim to support a wide range of Android versions, but there can be limitations based on the libraries and plugins you are using, as well as the minimum SDK version specified in your project.

Minimum SDK Version: Check the build.gradle file in your Android project (usually located at android/app/build.gradle). Look for the minSdkVersion setting. If it's set to a value higher than 24 (which corresponds to Android 7), your app won't run on Android 7 devices.

Plugin Compatibility: Some Capacitor plugins may require a minimum version higher than Android 7. Review the documentation for any plugins you are using to ensure they support Android 7.

WebView Compatibility: Older Android versions use older WebView implementations, which may not support newer JavaScript features or CSS. Ensure that your app's code is compatible with older browsers.
Testing on Real Device: Sometimes, emulators can behave differently than real devices. If possible, test on a physical Android 7 device to see if the issue persists.


